# ESP32 Hardware Serial - only write 1 byte at a time

Tags: arduino, serial-port, esp8266, esp32, arduino-c++

I'm using

```
Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, 15, 14,true);
Serial2.write(b,100);
```

To write a buffer to serial from the esp32

**But for some reason it doesn't transmit the full buffer ?**
Instead it transmit one byte at a time.

[image: data recived]

Any one have an advise on how I can transmit the full buffer, instead of 1 byte at a time ?

Code example:

```cpp
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial2.begin(9600, SERIAL_8N1, 15, 14,true); 
}

uint8_t buf[1000];

uint8_t* genBuffer(const char* txt, int* bufSZ)
{
    int index = 0;
    int i = 0;

    buf[index++] = 0x00;
    buf[index++] = 0x00;
    buf[index++] = 0x00;
    buf[index++] = 0x00;
    buf[index++] = 0x00;
    buf[index++] = 0x01;
    buf[index++] = 0x46;
    buf[index++] = 0x46;
    buf[index++] = 0x30;
    buf[index++] = 0x30;
    buf[index++] = 0x02;
    buf[index++] = 0x41;
    buf[index++] = 0x41;
    buf[index++] = 0x43;
    buf[index++] = 0x32;

    for (i = 0; txt[i]; i++) {
        buf[index++] = txt[i];
    }

    *bufSZ = index;

    return buf;
}

void loop()
{
    int sz = 0;
    uint8_t* b = genBuffer("test", &sz);     
    Serial.println(sz); 
    Serial2.write(b,sz);

    for (int i = 0; i < sz; i++) {  
        Serial.print(" ");
        Serial.print(b[i], HEX);
    }
    Serial.println();
    delay(5000);
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```

Comment: what is your buffer? this is C++ btw, not C

Comment: What baud rate is the UART set to, what transmission speed did you expect? "One byte at a time" is how you send a buffer, of course ...

Comment: 00 00 00 00 00 01 46 46 30 30 02 41 41 43 32 30 37 46 32 30 30 36 30 31 30.... @Piglet

Comment: please provide a [mcve], not just 2 lines of code

Comment: 9600baud
I mean in serial monitor / busdog it shows 1 byte of length 1 at a time.
Using usb/serial adapter this buffer shows all bytes in same transmission and a length of etc. 60 @unwind

Comment: @Piglet i have added code

Comment: Pls spend sometime to understand how c++ [arrays](https://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/) works, and how many of the functions in standard libraries like [cstdlib](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/) or in [cstring](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/) can be used in array/string manipulation, once you understand those, you will be able to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

As `Serial.write(buf,len)` isdefined

```
Serial: serial port object. See the list of available serial ports for each board on the Serial main page.
val: a value to send as a single byte.
str: a string to send as a series of bytes.
buf: an array to send as a series of bytes.
len: the number of bytes to be sent from the array.
```

You have to define e.g.

```
char b[] = "Two hundred and fiftyfive character have to be in here tomake theexample work ....";
```

then

```
 Serial2.write(b,100);
```

will work, or you define a fixed length buffer

```
 char b[256] = {'\0'};
```

and you fill values (converted to string) with `itoa, utoa, ftoa` into it with `strcpy` and `strcat` than you have to make sure that minimum 100 chars are in the buffer to write . If b is an int or similar the command igners  the `,100`  and behaves like `Serial.write(val)` -> value to send as a single byte!
**EDIT** The answer was given before the OP posted the code but as the buf is defined as global array there is no need to return it from a function
 You defined it as uint8 
 If you print your b to serial you'll see weird chars (probably terminator and some memory content) What should the prog do? As by

```
uint8_t* b
```

the pointer value is written to serial and not I guess the buffer from that pointer on - so what do you expect? See above usage from the docs.